# Stop Div from stacking improperly in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have used a CSS layout grid system (960.gs) It is a liquid system, and for some reason the header-right and content right divs are not staying on the same line to the right. Does anyone know why this would be? 
Thanks

[alt text http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/6575/screenshot20100810at104.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/6575/screenshot20100810at104.png)

Comment: What do you actually mean here? Post your HTML and CSS and you may get a useful answer.

Comment: I think this question is missing, well, the question. Describe your problem properly and show some code. The image is not really meaningful (and refused to load at all, wenn I first opened this page). (Edit: John A added some text now)

Comment: You really need to add your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

Perhaps you need to set explicit widths for your DIVs, if I guess correctly.

Give them either a float or a position in CSS, then force their width (also in CSS).

```
<div id='one' style='float:left;width:20%'>One</div>
<div id='two' style='float:left;width:80%'>Two</div>

<div id='three' style='float:left;width:20%'>Three</div>
<div id='four' style='float:left;width:80%'>Four</div>

<div id='five' style='float:left;width:20%'>Five</div>
<div id='six' style='float:left;width:80%'>Six</div>
```

etc.

UPDATED:

If the problem is to the right, then it's a similar solution.  It looks as though the borders, padding, or margin is throwing off the widths.  To use my example above...

```
<div id='five' style='float:right;width:20%'>Five</div>
<div id='six' style='float:right;width:80%;margin:5px'>Six</div>
```

Div Six will now appear on a different line since the 5px margin pushes it beyond 100%.